# building Atom problems

Tags: build, atom-editor, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca
and I was trying to build Atom from source as described here:
[GitHub/atom/linux][1]

I have error at the last step. Here is the output (where did I get wrong):

```
darko@darko-Lenovo-G570 ~/Downloads/atom $ script/build
Node: v0.10.33 npm: v1.4.28 Installing build modules...
Installing apm...
Package gnome-keyring-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gnome-keyring-1.pc' to the
PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable ...
```

I think that I am missing development headers for GNOME Keyring. But I don't know how to install them.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev`

Fixed it for me. See https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1948